# LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'boost_log_abi': value 'v2s_mt_nt5' doesn't match value 'v2s_mt_nt6'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, compiler-errors

After creating separate header file which consists of boost libraries, then I try to include in existing project.

But it shows the following error:

```
 ::  Error  15  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'boost_log_abi':
 value 'v2s_mt_nt5' doesn't match value 'v2s_mt_nt6' in BoostLogger.obj 
 E:\Projects\native\dcnotificationserver\loggerutil.obj  ::
```

I know that previous project works from Windows XP to Current Windows OS (i.e.)10 .

But I read that boost supports from Windows XP.

What is the problem?

How to solve it?

I think the problem due to windows version?

For further information, please ask me.

**EDIT:**
I'm using:
Compiler: msvc 10
Boost version: 1.60
Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar problem after upgrading both BOOST to 1.60 and Visual Studio to 2015.

I resolved it by changing/defining the _WIN32_WINNT definition in the preprocessor to be 0x601 vice 0x501.

I'm pretty sure this means...support Win7 and greater vice XP.

Comment: No. It must support from Windows XP.  So, I use boost 1.58

Comment: Using -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 fixed it for me today.  Using boost 1.63.0.  I think the project I am compiling was built a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, there are two solutions for this problem.

1) Use **boost 1.58** instead of using **boost 1.60**.

   [Note : you cannot use latest functions.]


2) Otherwise you can extract the files in boost 1.60  by using the cmd :
    ***b2 release define=BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0501***

 See here for more details :
http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_60_0.html

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution with out changing to old build.
You can use any build of boost library:
***b2 link=static runtime-link=static --toolset=msvc-10.0 define=BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0500***

It solve my problem when I used MS Visual Stdio 2010. You can also try with this.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I already done .It worked for me. Anyway Thanks.