# 'boost_log_abi': value 'v2s_mt_nt6' doesn't match value 'v2s_mt_nt5'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, visual-c++-2017

I am linking a C++ console application with Boost. Everything was fine till I start using Boost logging library. I am facing this issue:

> `boost_log_abi': value 'v2s_mt_nt6' doesn't match value 'v2s_mt_nt5`

I tried everything in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910432/lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-boost-log-abi-value-v2s-mt-nt5-doesnt-match). However, nothing worked.

I could not even understand what is the problem exactly. Which one is using an older version, my program or the boost?

I am on Windows 10, MSVC 2017 (141 toolset) and Boost 1.63.

Comment: Andrey's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394896/problems-linking-boost-log-1-60-with-mingw-on-windows-7) may help you.

Comment: @kenba unfortunately it did not work

Comment: This is definitely caused by the target Windows version mismatch between the built Boost.Log binary and your code (or maybe some other code that uses Boost.Log). The answer referenced by @kenba is the way forward, you only need to figure out where the inconsistency is coming from.